# How to change from Ruby On Rails version 6.0.3.2 to Version 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have installed Ruby On Rails version 6.0.3.2 but now I want to change it to Version 5. How can I do it?
Do I uninstall version 6 and install 5? What command should I use please?

Comment: Do you want to downgrade an existing application to Rails 5? And if so why? Or do you want to install multiple Rails versions at the same time on your machine and want to be able to choose which version to use when creating a new app?

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple versions of a gem installed:

```sh
gem install rails -v 5.2.4.4
```

And all modern rails versions have a way to select which specific one to use when creating a new app:

```sh
rails _5.2.4.4_ new application_name
```

If you want to downgrade an existing app - first search for a commit that upgraded it, if you're very lucky - a simple revert can do the job. But in more general case - you have to make your code compatible with older version (remove new feature usage etc), and fiddle with gem versions inside the `Gemfile`. Do a `bundle update` after edit - when a lower version is specified in requirements it will downgrade. Note that rails may be not the only gem requiring downgrade

Comment: Thanks guys for responses. I was advised to keep Ruby version 6 by my educator for the current project. But I will use these answers to install multiple versions for future projects.